# Web Scraping with Python: unexpected EOF while parsing error

Tags: python, web-scraping, eoferror

I'm following the exercises on the book 'Web Scraping with Python' but I get an 'unexpected EOF while parsing' error when running the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
try:
    html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html')
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
    # return null, break, or do some other "Plan B"
else:
    # program continues. Note: If you return or break in the
    # exception catch, you do not need to use the "else" statement
```

Any clues regarding what might be causing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After else: Why there is no code? If you use comment there, it will show that error. Instead of that provide simple pass or print statement. Then, there will not be any error.

Comment: in the book, they mentioned else without anything just for understanding. You have to put some code after the else. usually, if there's nothing to do in else part, you either remove else block or just put a pass in it.

Comment: yep that works fine for me it gives me a whole nice page with the whole "Lorem Ipsum", either your error isn't there or you're having other issues. Please provide an stacktrace

Comment: @yorodm after dropping the else as InAFlash suggested, the code ran but didn't return a "Lorem Ipsum". Did you add anything else to it?

Comment: Nope, and I doubt your networks behaves worse than mine. Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: File "...\scrapetest_error1.py", line 11
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing